# SQL query to add data from other table when data is not matching

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a SQL query to add data from other table when data is not matching.

For e.g. in the data table shown here, data for Pol 2 in TFT column is not present and so in the current output due to following query Pol 2 data is not coming.

But I need Pol 2 data to come up over there, the data unmatching with data table can be NULL.

Expected output is the output that should be returned.

SQL query:

```
select distinct 
    b.Primary_Brand_Key as "Primary_Brand",
    a.Market "Market",
    Year "Year",
    Month "Month",
    Category "Category",
    Medium "Medium",
    b.Reach,                        
    concat(Month,' ',Year) "Period_Type",
    a.TFT as TFT,
    a.TG,   
    b.Perc as Perc, b.Value as Value
from 
    dbo.data  a
left join
    dbo.perc b on a.TFT = b.TFT
               and a.Market = b.Market 
               and a.TG = b.TG
               and a.Primary_Brand_Key = b.Primary_Brand_Key
```

`Perc` table:

| Brand | TG | TFT | Market | Perc | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lemon Tea | Female | Pol 1 | Warsaw | 88.61% | 2.09 |
| Lemon Tea | Female | Pol 2 | Warsaw | 64.64% | 11.32 |
| Lemon Tea | Female | Pol 3 | Warsaw | 27.41% | 19.75 |

`Data` table:

| Medium | Primary_Brand_Key | Month | Year | Market | Campaign | TG | TFT | Reach |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TV | Lemon Tea | May | 2021 | Warsaw |  | Female | Pol 1 | 0.19 |
| TV | Lemon Tea | May | 2021 | Warsaw |  | Female | Pol 3 | 0.11 |

Current output:

| Brand | Market | Year | Month | Category | Medium | Reach | Period_Type | TFT | TG | Perc | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lemon Tea | Warsaw | 2021 | May |  | TV | 0.19 | May-21 | Pol 1 | Female | 88.61% | 2.09 |
| Lemon Tea | Warsaw | 2021 | May |  | TV | 0.11 | May-21 | Pol 3 | Female | 27.41% | 19.75 |

Desired output:

| Brand | Market | Year | Month | Category | Medium | Reach | Period_Type | TFT | TG | Perc | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lemon Tea | Warsaw | 2021 | May |  | TV | 0.19 | May-21 | Pol 1 | Female | 88.61% | 2.09 |
| Lemon Tea | Warsaw | 2021 | May |  | NULL | NULL | May-21 | Pol 2 | Female | 64.64% | 11.32 |
| Lemon Tea | Warsaw | 2021 | May |  | TV | 0.11 | May-21 | Pol 3 | Female | 27.41% | 19.75 |

Answer (score 2):

Left outer join operation is being performed between **Data** and **Perc**. So Data has 2 records and during left outer join only 2 records will come in the output.
So you can use as below.

```
-- #temp is perc
SELECT 'LEMON TEA' AS BRAND,'FEMALE' AS TG,'POL 1' AS TFT,'WARSAW' AS MARKET,'88.61%' AS PERC,2.09  AS VALUE 
INTO #TEMP UNION ALL
SELECT 'LEMON TEA' AS BRAND,'FEMALE' AS TG,'POL 2' AS TFT,'WARSAW' AS MARKET,'64.64%' AS PERC,11.32 AS VALUE UNION ALL
SELECT 'LEMON TEA' AS BRAND,'FEMALE' AS TG,'POL 3' AS TFT,'WARSAW' AS MARKET,'27.41%' AS PERC,19.75 AS VALUE 

-- #temp2 is data
SELECT 'TV' AS MEDIUM,'LEMON TEA' AS PRIMARY_BRAND_KEY,'MAY' AS MONTH,2021 AS YEAR,'WARSAW' AS MARKET, '' AS CAMPAIGN, 'FEMALE' AS TG ,'POL 1' AS TFT ,0.19 AS REACH 
INTO #TEMP2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'TV' AS MEDIUM,'LEMON TEA' AS PRIMARY_BRAND_KEY,'MAY' AS MONTH,2021 AS YEAR,'WARSAW' AS MARKET, '' AS CAMPAIGN, 'FEMALE' AS TG ,'POL 3' AS TFT ,0.11 AS REACH

SELECT DISTINCT A.BRAND AS "PRIMARY_BRAND",
A.MARKET "MARKET",
B.YEAR "YEAR",
B.MONTH "MONTH",
CAMPAIGN "CATEGORY",
MEDIUM "MEDIUM",
B.REACH,                        
CONCAT(MONTH,' ',YEAR) "PERIOD_TYPE",                        
A.TFT AS TFT,
A.TG,   
A.PERC AS PERC , A.VALUE AS VALUE
FROM #TEMP  A
LEFT JOIN #TEMP2 B
ON A.TFT = B.TFT
AND A.MARKET = B.MARKET 
AND A.TG=B.TG
AND A.BRAND=B.PRIMARY_BRAND_KEY
```

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks @Srishuk for this one.

Can you please help me know of any way I can bring year & Month data also in the final output.

Comment: @AaronBertrand from when 'please' has turned into yelling, it was simply a request. Having more reputation doesn't necessarily mean you will understand everything. Kindly be nice to others

Anyhow I am reporting your comment

Comment: @Akash What are you even talking about? I was asking why the answer converted you entire query from `lower case` to `UPPER CASE` (commonly called “YELLING”), which can cause a problem if you use a case sensitive or binary collation. Not sure how that is being interpreted as “not nice” - please assume best intent from people who have been participating in this community for over a decade.